# How can I get child class attributes from a hashMap containing parent class as entryset in Java?

Tags: java

```
public class SuperVertex extends Vertex{
    int childAttr = 1;
}

public class Vertex {
   int name = 0;
}

public class Test {
    SuperVertex sv = new SuperVertex();
    Vertex v = new Vertex();
    HashMap<Vertex, Vertex> hmp = new HashMap<Vertex, Vertex>();
    hmp.put(v,v);
    hmp.put(sv,sv);
    hmp.get(v).name //works
    hmp.get(sv).name //works
    hmp.get(sv).childAttr //doesn't work
}
```

As code shows above I can't access childAttribute since I get a parent type object from HashMap. How can I create a HashMap containing both Parent and Child type objects and reach Child objects properties?

Comment: Yes but than I can't put Vertex type objects into the HashMap

Comment: You would need to check if `hmp.get(key) instanceof SuperVertex`, and cast.

Comment: You have to cast `((SuperVertex) hmp.get(sv)).childAttr`

Comment: This has nothing to do with `HashMap`, it's just pure java class hierarchy stuff. As other have suggested in previous comments, you cast from one type to another.

Comment: I see thank you for the information. I can't believe that I missed something so obvious.

Answer (score 1):

```
(SuperVertex)hmp.get(sv).childAttr//works
```

Casting to the correct type fixes the problem. Thanks to @Miguel Gamboa and @nolexa.